# AWS public dns name gmail encryption warning message

Tags: amazon-web-services

Aws public DNS name showing in Gmail Not Encryption message. Please find the screen shot. Can you please advise how to mask this to avoid to show.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysWNE.png)

Comment: Can you provide more details what you are using and how encryption is handled?

Comment: I didn't use any encryption method. I'm using aws instance for sending mails to customers. When sending i'm getting this message under subject line. Please see attached image. Please tell me how to mask public dns to my website name.

Comment: What code are you using? TO send emails.

Comment: I need to show like this - > https://postimg.org/image/4xlkje5ap/

Comment: Yes but I need to check the code first how you are sending the email

Comment: @error2007s Twilio REST Calls

Comment: Check this https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/05/send-and-receive-sms-messages-via-email-with-twilio-and-sendgrid.html